# Data to remain after hitting Insert Button

Tags: php, mysql

In this form when you click on a record from the table that data appears on the form in left. When I click on the Insert button, data gets stored in the database and disappears from the form like there's no record. Is there any way to make the records stay even after I hit the Insert button.

[image]

this is my php code for the insertion.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];
    $LabourSupplier = $_POST['LabourSupplier'];
    $BasicSalary = $_POST['BasicSalary'];
    $Allowance1 = $_POST['Allowance1'];
    $InTime = $_POST['InTime'];
    $OutTime = $_POST['OutTime'];
    $Day = $_POST['Day'];
    $DayRate = $_POST['DayRate'];
    $Salary = $_POST['Salary'];
    $OtHours = $_POST['OtHours'];
    $OTrate = $_POST['OTrate'];
    $OTAmount = $_POST['OTAmount'];
    $Allowance2 = $_POST['Allowance2'];
    $TotalSalary = $_POST['TotalSalary'];
    $Advance = $_POST['Advance'];
    $SalaryTo = $_POST['SalaryTo'];
    $Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
    $Home = $_POST['Home'];

//Insert Query of SQL
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendance(ID,Name,Location, Date,Category,LabourSupplier,BasicSalary,Allowance1,InTime,OutTime,Day,DayRate,Salary,OTHours,OTrate,OTAmount,Allowance2,TotalSalary,Advance,SalaryToHand, Mobile, Home) VALUES ('$ID','$Name','$Location' ,'$Date', '$Category','$LabourSupplier','$BasicSalary','$Allowance1','$InTime','$OutTime','$Day','$DayRate','$Salary','$OtHours','$OTrate','$OTAmount','$Allowance2','$TotalSalary','$Advance','$SalaryTo','$Mobile','$Home')",$connection);

        }
    ?>
```

this is the html code of the form.

```
<form id="details" action="" method="POST">

    <fieldset> ID:
        <input class="input" type="text" id="id" name="ID" value="" />
      </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Name:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="Name" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Location:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="location" name="Location" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Date:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="date" name="Date" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Category:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="category" name="Category" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Labour Supplier:
     <input class="input" type="text" id="labsupp" name="LabourSupplier" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Basic Salary:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="bsalary" name="BasicSalary" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Allowance I:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="all1" name="Allowance1" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> In-Time:
     <input class="input" type="text" name="InTime" id="intime" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Out-Time:
      <input class="input" type="text" name="OutTime" id="outtime" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Day:
     <input class="input" type="text" id="day" name="Day" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Day Rate:
    <input class="input" type="text" id="dayrate" name="DayRate" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>Salary:
     <input class="input" type="text" id="salary" name="Salary" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>OT Hours:
     <input class="input" type="text" id="othours" name="OtHours" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>OT Rate:
     <input class="input" type="text" id="otrate" name="OTrate" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> OT Amount:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="otamount" name="OTAmount" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Allownace II:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="allowance2" name="Allowance2" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Total Salary:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="totalsalary" name="TotalSalary" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Advance:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="advance" name="Advance" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Salary To Hand:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="salaryto" name="SalaryTo" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Mobile:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="mobile" name="Mobile" value="" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> Home:
      <input class="input" type="text" id="home" name="Home" value="" />
    </fieldset> <br>
    <fieldset >
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Insert</button>
      <button name="update" type="submit" id="update">Update</button>
      <button name="delete" type="delete" id="delete">Delete</button>
      <button onclick="win();" name="Back" type="back" id="details-back">Back</button>
    </fieldset>

  </form>
```

Comment: please post the html

Comment: Instead of form `post`, use jquery `ajax()` method.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use ajax, which basically allows you to post the data without reloading the page (which is what clears your form fields). Details of this can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ but a simple example is something like the below:

```
$.post("myscript.php", function(data) {
  alert("record added!");
});
```

Alternatively when you post your data you could just check for it in each of your form fields and put it in again. So for example with your ID field you can do something like:

```
<input class="input" type="text" id="id" name="ID" value="<?php isset($_POST['ID']) ? $_POST['ID'] : false; ?>" />
```

You may need to do something like this anyway if you have any sort of error checking on your form, so if they enter something invalid and it fails to insert you want to retain all of the field data rather than clear it.